# Reachability reachabilityWithAddress does not work

Tags: iphone, reachability

I am trying to determine if the iphone can connect to my IP address using following code

```
struct sockaddr_in server_address;   
server_address.sin_len = sizeof(server_address);
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons(8888);
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("1.2.3.4");
Reachability *r = [[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&server_address ] retain];
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
```

But it always says that the status is 'Reachable' regarless of what I give in the IP address.
Am I doing anything wrong? Why won't this work? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Try turning off the Wi-Fi and 3G then running the test.

Comment: add [r startNotifier]; before checking status

Comment: Shouldn't you be using struct sockaddr (not struct sockaddr_in)?

Answer (score 0):

checkout this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5875059/1067154)

[SCNetworkReachability Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html)

> The SCNetworkReachability programming interface allows an application
>   to determine the status of a system's current network configuration
>   and the reachability of a target host.
>
> A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an
>   application into the network stack, can leave the local device.
>   Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be
>   received by the host.