# iOS network reachability - doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ios, networking, reachability

I'm following [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk) and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html to test for connectivity, but am running into some pretty basic issues.

For example, I'm running a .NET API off of another machine and then trying to connect to it via my mac mini.

1) When IIS is running, everything is working like it should, I was excited that I got this working!

2) I can shut off IIS completely (obviously, host is unreachable) but my reachabilityWithHostName is still reporting that the host is reachable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [SCNetworkReachability Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html).

> The SCNetworkReachability programming
>   interface allows an application to
>   determine the status of a system's
>   current network configuration and the
>   reachability of a target host. **A
>   remote host is considered reachable
>   when a data packet, sent by an
>   application into the network stack,
>   can leave the local device.
>   Reachability does not guarantee that
>   the data packet will actually be
>   received by the host.**

Turning IIS on and off is just preventing your server from receiving web request such as ftp/http and does not stop the device from successfully sending a data packet out.

Comment: Ah - thank you, that makes sense. How would I actually test if my web service is up then??

Comment: Do a GET or HEAD request and look for a 200 - OK message using NSURLConnection or ASIHttpRequest

Answer (score 4):

A while ago I used this answer to solve my problem. I found a better solution and I am posting it here for others who may find it helpful.

There is a nice sample code provided by Apple.

Download the sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Include the Reachability.h and Reachability.m files in your project. Take a look at ReachabilityAppDelegate.m to see an example on how to determine host reachability, reachability by WiFi, by WWAN etc. For a very simply check of network reachability, you can do something like this

```
Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];   
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];    
if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {        
    NSLog(@"There IS NO internet connection");        
} else {        

     NSLog(@"There IS internet connection");        


    }        
}
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question. What he want is to check whether a ip connection is actually existing or not.