# Check if server is available over network using apple Reachability library

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4, reachability

I am currently using this code below provided by Apples "Reachability" library to check if a server is connected:

```
Reachability* reachability = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"192.168.0.1"] retain];

NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if (netStatus == NotReachable)
{
    NSLog(@"NotReachable");
}

if (netStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    NSLog(@"ReachableViaWiFi");
}

if (netStatus == ReachableViaWWAN)
{
    NSLog(@"ReachableViaWWAN");
}
```

The only thing is when I disconnect the server from the network it still displays in the NSLOG that it is still reachable no matter what network connection the device is currently using.

So what is the point of the host name entry and how do I check if my server is online or not with this Reachability provided by apple? 
([Apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/))

I tried using `[[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:<#(const struct sockaddr_in *)] retain];` but it got so confusing and seems very unsupported by the majority of the ios community.

Comment: In my opinion there *is* no point.  Reachability will only tell you whether or not you are connected to a network that has the potential to reach the server, and not if the server is actually reachable.  To do that, you need to actually send a message to it and have it send one back.  Using the sockaddr_in version will not help.

Comment: If you are catching an error with NSURLConnection request or with the webview delegate method `webView:didFailLoadWithError:`, you can check if the error is du to connection to host by testing `[error code] == -1004`

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS network reachability - doesn't seem to be working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874445/ios-network-reachability-doesnt-seem-to-be-working)

Comment: So what is the point of reachabilityWithHostName if it dose not detect if the host address is available or not?