# Reachability class and hostnames that require https or vpn (ios)

Tags: ios, networking, connection, reachability

I have implemented the Reachability class successfully.  However, in my app I'd like to notify the user when a connection to our server only can't be made (but the regular internet is working).

Reachability is reporting that the iPhone successfully can reach a hostname, when I thought it might return an error b/c I was not on an authenticated network:

The hostname I use is 'foreverfreebank.com'.  Again, Reachability's hostname check reports success.

However,

--to access this site via the web, one needs to use https in the browser, i.e. 'https://foreverfreebank.com'

Does Reachability account for this case?  Or does the protocol part ('https') not count for anything?

I am confused b/c if you type in in the Firefox browser 'http://foreverfreebank.com', (leaving out the 's'), you get an error.  That is, http:// should NOT be reachable.

Similarly, I have another site that requires VPN access to get to the site: http://checksforever.com.  When I try the hostname: 'checksforever.com', Reachability reports success even though I am not on VPN.

Is this expected behavior?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check reachability on a specific port (443 in this case). This is something that is not supported by Reachability API. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886788/iphone-reachability-test-for-specific-ip-port), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874445/ios-network-reachability-doesnt-seem-to-be-working/5875059#5875059).

Relevant part from documentation:

> A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an
>   application into the network stack, can leave the local device.
>   Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be
>   received by the host.

So, basically Reachability doesn't test if the remote host accepts incoming connections. For this purpose, I suspect you'll need to open an URL connection and wait for time out/other errors.

Comment: Thanks for these links.  There is a clear distinction that needs to be made which I am unaware of.  Reachability means that the iPhone can send a packet out, but it says nothing about whether the  host can reply (aka a ping function).  What is the point of the remote host function then vs the check general internet connectivity?

Comment: Reachability goes one step further than a simple check on whether WiFi/3G is connected. (Now that I think about it, it's the only way to check for WiFi connection, is it not?). Perhaps https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000716-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 could help you.