# reachability test for specific ip/port

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, reachability

I'm trying to check if an address and Port are available. For that I follow the different steps in this  post [(iphone) reachability test for specific ip/port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886788/iphone-reachability-test-for-specific-ip-port) and my code  :

```
BOOL hasLeadingNumberInString(NSString* s) {
    if (s)
        return [s length] && isnumber([s characterAtIndex:0]);
    else
        return NO;
}

-(BOOL)networkConnected: (NSString *)ipAdress Port:(int)port {
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags  flags = 0;
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef    netReachability;
    BOOL                        retrievedFlags = NO;

    // added the "if" and first part of if statement
    //
    if (hasLeadingNumberInString(ipAdress)) {
        struct sockaddr_in the_addr;
        memset((void *)&the_addr, 0, sizeof(the_addr));
        the_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        the_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        const char* server_addr = [ipAdress UTF8String];
        unsigned long ip_addr = inet_addr(server_addr);
        the_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ip_addr;
        netReachability =    SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, (struct sockaddr*)&the_addr);
    } else {
        netReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, [ipAdress UTF8String]);
    }
    if (netReachability) {
        retrievedFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(netReachability, &flags);
        CFRelease(netReachability);
    }
    if (!retrievedFlags || !flags) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But I always have NO even if couple address/port exist. What I'm doing wrong??

EDIT LOG:

```
netReachability is NIL
```

Comment: The answer to the question that you linked to explicitely states that SCNetworkReachability *cannot be used* to check for the availability of a specific host/port.

Comment: What is the contents of the `ipAdress` string?

Comment: yes the contents is string

Comment: Yes, but what string? Show it to us!

Comment: [self networkConnected:@"192.168.1.45" Port:1785]  ipAdress is equal to @"192.168.1.45"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_addr.sin_len = sizeof(the_addr);`

You forgot to set this part of the struct.  Without it, it will be interpreted as zero-length (invalid).  If you set it, your `SCNetworkReachabilityRef` will no longer be `NULL`.

Comment: Did not see your answer while writing mine!

Comment: @MartinR Yours has some extra info anyway ^^

Answer (score 2):

The `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress()` fails because you forgot to set

```
the_addr.sin_len = sizeof(the_addr);
```

If you add that it should work.

But note that the SCNetworkReachability functions only check if a packet can be *routed*
to the destination. It does *not verify* if a host is actually listening at the given port.

Therefore, the port number is irrelevant, and you could just use

```
netReachability  = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, server_addr);
```

without all the `struct sockaddr_in` hassle.

Comment: Actually the entire server is really irrelevant.  You could use any IP address you wanted (even invalid ones) and as long as you are connected to the Internet Reachability will be satisfied.

Comment: Because this method does not give the expected result, what you propose me or suggest me to test whether a port and address are available?

Comment: @iPisix: The only way it to actually *connect* to that host/port. You can use the "low-level" `connect()` or perhaps higher level frameworks , see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Comment: I found solution with "SOCKET"