# Verify if a specific port and address are enable (Reachability) in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, wifi

I am trying to know if a specific address and port are enable and reachability before to start to get data. Unfortunately I found a lot of examples but only verify if Wifi is enable. I need an answer in Swift 3 with port and address, not only and address. Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not what the Reachability API is for. You should just try to connect to the host and port. Apple's network programming guide can help you with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886788/iphone-reachability-test-for-specific-ip-port.